# Prolog: Checking if the first and last character of a string are left and right squiggly brackets('{' & '}')

Tags: string, prolog, equality

I am very new to prolog, so assume that I know very little terminology.
I am using swipl in SWI-prolog.

I want to check if a string starts with a left squiggly bracket('{') and ends with a right squiggly bracket('}'}

Some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707026/find-out-if-first-letter-is-a-vowel-prolog) that I have read online have lead me to program the following into my knowledge base to check if the string starts with a left squiggly bracket.

```
start_left_squiggle([Letter|_]):-
     Letter = '{'.
```

But when I run this function, I get false, when I expect it to return true.

```
?- start_left_squiggle('{hello').
false.
```

As well, [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734799/getting-last-char-of-a-string-in-prolog) that seem correct for checking the if the last character is a squiggly bracket have lead me to code the following.

```
last_char(str, X):-
    name(S, N), 
    reverse(N, [F|_]),
    name(X, [F]).

end_right_squiggle(Werd):-
    last_char(Werd, Last),
    Last = '}'.
```

And I again get false when running the function, when I expect it to return true.

```
?- end_right_squiggle('hello}').
false.
```

Comment: `'hello}'` here you don't have two curly brackets at begining and end so you should get false.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I am performing tests on the two functions separately. The first function should return true if the string starts with a '{' and the second function should return true if the string ends with a '}'. What the string ends with is irrelevant to the first function and what the string starts with is irrelevant to the second function.

Comment: The easy way is to convert the string into a list and then try to do further operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to break the atom into list of characters like this:

```
start_with_left(H):-
   atom_chars(H,X), %here x is a list
   X = [L|_],  %get the head of the list which is frist element an compare
   L == '{'.
```

You can use a recursive definition to check righ side of the `atom` after converting the atom into list of characters and when length of the list is `1` then compare it with bracket , it means if last element is same you should get `true` otherwise `False`.

Right is like this, it's same but we need last element so we have to use recursion:

```
start_with_right(H):-
    atom_chars(H,X), %here x is a list
    length(X,Y),
    check_at_end(X,Y).

check_at_end([H|_],1):-
    H == '}'.

check_at_end([_|T],Y):-
    NewY is Y -1,
    check_at_end(T,NewY).
```

.

Comment: In the line `H == '}',!.` what is the ! doing

Comment: You can remove it , it will still work, it's called cut and i can't explain it in comments.I edit it again

Answer (score 3):

Use `sub_atom(Atom, Before, Length, After, Subatom)`  like so:

```
?- sub_atom('{abc}',0,1,_,C).
   C = '{'.
?- sub_atom('{abc}',_,1,0,C).
   C = '}'.
```

Or just test:

```
?- sub_atom('{abc}',0,1,_,'{').
   true.
?- sub_atom('{abc}',_,1,0,'}').
   true.
```